# Regex: How to not include a regex if is in another regex

Tags: php, regex

Here is my problem: I have a php file which contain this "html" code:

```
<div>
    {{ '{# Hi :D #}' }} {# Hello #}
    {{ $model }}
</div>
```

In my code I want to get the {# #} and the {{ }} to do different regex replacement but not the one that are in {{ }}.

The problem here is that if I do in the same (in PHP) preg_replace for the two possible match, this doesn't take the {{ }} found (That's what I want) but the replacement will be the same for the two:

```
/{{(.*?)}}|{#(.*?)#}/
```

This is logic but I want to do different replacements for each $1 and $2 match.

I thought to those possibilities :

- First is to tell the regex to do not take the strings that are in the "{{ }}" parent but after multiple tentatives I failed to.
- Second possibility is to add another replacement, in the preg_replace function you can do an array() replacement but this doesn't work like $1 = the first replacement and $2 = the second replacement, there is a replacement per regex request.

After 2 days trying to create this magic regex I finally ask a question in stackoverflow, hope someone will found the answer to this regex

Thanks,

Comment: Curly brackets are special characters in regex, used for specifying quantifiers. Make sure you're escaping them if you want to match them literally.

Comment: There is no differences if I escape them or not, I don't know if this is only a thing in PHP but well, it works escaped or not

Comment: Use `preg_match_all`, if in index 1 it is `{{(.*?)}}`, if in index 2 it is `{#(.*?)#}`.

Comment: Yeah sure but what if I want to keep the `'{# Hi :D #}'` in the `{{ }}`? I want to change the `{# Hello #}` but not the things in the `{{ }}` and what if I have multiple `{# #}`, the indexes doesn't work anymore

Comment: Could you post what your desired result is?  I'm having trouble deciphering what "`{# #}` and the `{{ }}` to do different regex replacement but not the one that are in `{{ }}`" could possibly mean.  You want `x` and `y` to do different things but not the ones that are in `y`.  Sometimes you want `y` to do something and other times to not do something?  That's gonna be a bit tough ;)

Comment: I want to 
`<div>
    {{ '{# Hi :D #}' }} {# Hello #}
    {{ $model }}
</div>` becoming `<div>
    <?php echo '{# Hi :D #}'; ?> <?php //Hello ?>
    <?php echo $model; ?>
</div>`. And for your exemple yes, that's what I want, `x` do a thing and `y` another thing but if `x` is in `y`, only `y` is choosen, not `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

Here's an approach using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag in order to **tokenize the string and account for nested tags**.

```php
$tokens = [
  // token definition as [open_tag, close_tag, replacement]
  ['{{', '}}', '<?php echo \1; ?>'],
  ['{#', '#}', '<?php //\1 ?>']
];

$open_tags = array_column($tokens, 0);
$close_tags = array_column($tokens, 1, 0); // mapped by open tag
$replacements = array_column($tokens, 2, 0); // mapped by open tag

$token_regex = '/(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $open_tags + $close_tags)) . ')/';

$parts = preg_split($token_regex, $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$output = '';
while (null !== ($part = array_shift($parts))) {

  // open tag found...
  if (in_array($part, $open_tags)) {
    // ...start building string of full tag
    $tag_body = $part;
    // ...watch for corresponding close tag
    $close_at = [ $close_tags[$part] ];
    while (0 < count($close_at)) {
      $inner_part = array_shift($parts);
      if (in_array($inner_part, $open_tags)) {
        // nested tag found, add its closing to watchlist
        array_unshift($close_at, $close_tags[$inner_part]);
      } else {
        // close tag found, remove from watchlist
        if (reset($close_at) === $inner_part) {
          array_shift($close_at);
        }
      }
      $tag_body .= $inner_part;
    }

    // substitute full tag with replacement
    $tag_regex = '/^' . preg_quote($part) . '\s*(.*?)\s*' . preg_quote($close_tags[$part]) . '$/';
    $part = preg_replace($tag_regex, $replacements[$part], $tag_body);
  }

  $output .= $part;
}

echo $output;
```

You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/LkOA).

Comment: Well, it's a big step forward but what if you want to do `{# {{ 'Hello' }} #}`? This will transform to `{# <?php echo 'Hello'; ?> #}` whitout event taking care of the commentary's rule which is bad, I think the regex need to understand if there is something inside a parent regex. But the idea is here.

Comment: Do you also need to account for nested cases, such as `{# {# 'Hello' #} #}` or `{{ '{{ Hi :D }}' }}`?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want